# Are there any comments in the mahabarata or the upanishades on whether Krishna fulfilled the prophecy that he would restore dharma?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

EDIT :I i only accept answers based purely on mahabharata or uphanishades.

This is in no way opinion based, I am looking for an unbiased answer.
Does Krishna himself comment on how he feels about this?

For example
There is a story where after the war at old age Krishna naps under a tree and is shaken by the pain of the war. He dreams about dharma. I can't find this story, maybe it gives a perspective on this

As I understand the moral of this is that not even a divine hero Krishna can act against the free will of people, as they must deal with their own karma.

But the what can you really ever do for anybody or against anybody, as all that happens is simply karma

Answer (score 2):

Srimad Bhagavatam --3.2.15

sva-śānta-rūpeṣv itaraiḥ sva-rūpair
abhyardyamāneṣv anukampitātmā
parāvareśo mahad-amśa-yukto
hy ajo 'pi jāto bhagavān yathāgniḥ

,        ,        ,     ,           ,            .

-- ..

Śrī Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa, accompanied by Balarāma and surrounded by the Yadu dynasty, executed the killing of many demons. Then, further to remove the burden of the earth, the Lord arranged for the great Battle of Kurukṣetra, which suddenly erupted in violence between the Kurus and the Pāṇḍavas. 1.

Because the sons of Pāṇḍu were enraged by the numerous offenses of their enemies, such as duplicitous gambling, verbal insults, the seizing of Draupadī’s hair, and many other cruel transgressions, the Supreme Lord engaged those Pāṇḍavas as the immediate cause to execute His will. On the pretext of the Battle of Kurukṣetra, Lord Kṛṣṇa arranged for all the kings who were burdening the earth to assemble with their armies on opposite sides of the battlefield, and when the Lord killed them through the agency of war, the earth was relieved of its burden. 2.

bhū-bhāra-rāja-pṛtanā yadubhir nirasya
guptaiḥ sva-bāhubhir acintayad aprameyaḥ
manye 'vaner nanu gato 'py agataṁ hi bhāraṁ
yad yādavaṁ kulam aho aviṣahyam āste

The Supreme Personality of Godhead used the Yadu dynasty, which was protected by His own arms, to eliminate the kings who with their armies had been the burden of this earth. Then the unfathomable Lord thought to Himself, “      ’    ,        ,      ā  ,       .” 3.

naivānyataḥ paribhavo 'sya bhavet kathañcin
mat-samśrayasya vibhavonnahanasya nityam
antaḥ kaliṁ yadu-kulasya vidhāya veṇu-
stambasya vahnim iva śāntim upaimi dhāma

Lord Kṛṣṇa thought, “           ,   ,               .         ,                 ,              .” 4.

My dear King Parīkṣit, when the supreme almighty Lord, whose desire always comes to pass(Satya sankalpa), had thus made up His mind, He withdrew His own family on the pretext of a curse spoken by an assembly of brāhmaṇas. 5.

The Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, is the reservoir of all beauty. All beautiful things emanate from Him, and His personal form is so attractive that it steals the eyes away from all other objects, which then seem devoid of beauty in comparison to Him. When Lord Kṛṣṇa was on the earth, He attracted the eyes of all people. When Kṛṣṇa spoke, His words attracted the minds of all who remembered them. By seeing the footsteps of Lord Kṛṣṇa, people became attracted to Him, and thus they wanted to offer their bodily activities to the Lord as His followers. In this way Kṛṣṇa very easily spread His glories, which are sung throughout the world by the most sublime and essential Vedic verses.  ṛṣṇ         ,             .     ,      . 6,7.

Comment: I shouldn't have included the puranas. I am mostly interested in the mahabharata itself. Not the puranas

Comment: artho ‘yam brahma-sutranam
bharatartha-vinirnayah......  " The meaning of the Brahma-sutra is present in Srimad-Bhagavatam. The full purport of the Mahabharata is also there. "                                          This is a famous Shloka attributed to Garuda Purana.

Comment: As I said, I shouldn't have mentioned the puranas

Answer (score -1):

I believe this answers it. https://www.google.com/search?q=18+says+Krishna+soeaks&oq=18+says+Krishna+soeaks&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i10i160.7017j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#

Krishna says that the war and the bravery of all  its heroes will help guide  people in the kali yuga overcome their demons, and without kali yuga, the sundown , there couldn't be a new dawn

This is just the animated illustrated message of the mahabarata itself.